# Flutter TabBarView cover bottom area (Slider) in iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, uitabbar

I am relatively new in Flutter and I write simple TabBarView like this.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
       theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: HexColor("#2E58A1"),
      ), 
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: new Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              new Page1(),
              new Page2(),
              new Page3(),
              new Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: new TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.rss_feed),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
              ),
              Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.settings),)
            ],
            labelColor: HexColor("#2E58A1"),
            unselectedLabelColor: HexColor("#CBCCCD"),
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            indicatorColor: HexColor("#2E58A1"),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In native iOS application, it doesn't overlap tabbar and slider like this.

[image]

How shall I re-write my code?

Comment: In flutter Scaffold itself provided bottomNavigationBar which takes in a widget, check some tutorials for it.

https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap your **MaterialApp** with **SafeArea** widget.

or you can just wrap your **TabBar** with **SafeArea**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: SafeArea(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: new Scaffold(
            body: TabBarView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                new Page1(),
                new Page2(),
                new Page3(),
                new Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.rss_feed),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.settings),
                )
              ],
              labelColor: HexColor("#2E58A1"),
              unselectedLabelColor: HexColor("#CBCCCD"),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              indicatorColor: HexColor("#2E58A1"),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got error in rendering. How shall I solve? I try to wrap with MediaQuery and not okay.
SafeArea widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.

Comment: Try to wrap your Tabbar with safearea only

Comment: it worked! thank you. can you also update your answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget into [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) it adds sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system

Would also suggest setting

```
BottomNavigationBar(
...
elevation: 0,
```

as per this report: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21688

Comment: I got error in rendering. How shall I solve? I try to wrap with MediaQuery and not okay. SafeArea widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.